# Workflow: Wait for field change in current item does not fire

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, workflow, designer-workflow

I have a work flow that looks like this:

wait for field to be not empty

email people

wait for field to be not empty

email people

The problem is that from some reason, some of the time (it is not consistent), the second "wait for" does not work.

The workflows status say **In Progress** and the description says it is waiting for that field to not be empty even though the field has something in it and thus not empty.

Does anyone know why this may be happening?

Answer (score 1):

I experienced similiar trouble. I believe the problem to be the timing SharePoint kicks off the workflow when documents are uploaded.  Workflows kick off immidiately after a file is uploaded--prior to metadata entry.  I solved this problem by pausing the workflow initially to allow users to enter in metadata.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, though I am not sure this is the same problem. This problem happens well after the document has been uploaded. Here is the process:  
  
Person 1 fills out form and attaches document, then submits.  

An email is sent to Person 2.
Workflow waits for field to not be empty.  Person 2 edits the item and fills in the field and hits submit.  
Workflow does not see that field is not empty.